# How to determine if a given word or phrase from a list is within an anchor tag?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have a ColdFusion based site that involves a large number of 'document authors' that have little or no knowledge of HTML.  The 'documents' they create are comprised of HTML stored in a table in the database.  They use a CKEDITOR interface.  The content that they create is output into specific area of the page.  The document frequently has tons of technical terms that readers may not be familiar with that we would like to have tooltips automatically show up for.

I and the other programmer want to have some code insert 'tooltip' code into the page based on a list of words in a table on our SQL server.  The 'dictionary' table in our database has a unique ID, the word/phrase we will look for and a corresponding definition that would be displayed in the tooltip.

For instance, one of the word/phrases we will be looking for is 'Scrum Master'.  If it occurs in the document area, we need to insert code around the words to create a tooltip.  To do that, we need to see if certain conditions exist.  Are the words within an anchor tag?  If yes, is there already a title value for the tag (title is used to contain the info to be displayed in a tooltip)?  If a title tag exists, don't do anything.  If the words are not in an anchor tag, then we would put anchor tags around the words along with the title that will contain the definition.

The tooltip code we use is via jQuery (http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).  It is quick and simple to use.  We just need to figure out how to use it dynamically based on our dictionary table.

Do you have any suggestions of how to go about this?

I was hoping that [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) might have a function that I could use, but that doesn't seem to be the right technology for what I want to do, but I could be wrong and I am happy to be corrected!

We have a large number of these documents and so manually inserting and maintaining the tooltip code is just not an option.

Comment: jSoup is exactly the right technology. e.g. Use the selector `a:contains(text)` to find all anchor tags containing the text, or `p:containsOwn(text)`  to find all paragraphs that contain the text directly (i.e. not in a sub-tag), or something similar. You can also do `:matches(regex)` and `:matchesOwn(regex)` if you want to add word boundary checks.

Answer (score 0):

Update you content with something like:

```
strOut = ReplaceList(strIn, ValueList(qryTT.find), ValueList(qryTT.replace));
```

Since words are delimited by spaces, the qryTT.find needs to have spaces. The replace column is going to need to include some of the original content. You are going to have to be careful with words followed by a comma or a period too.

I would cache the results because I would expect it to be memory intensive.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but inserting the tooltip code isn't the issue.  It is testing to see if the string we are looking for is inside of anchor tags <a>. . . </a>.

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009330/matching-nesting-tags

Comment: If looking for 'scrum master' and it is <a href="someurl" title="scrum definition">scrum master</a> then I would ignore that occurrence because it is within the anchor tag and has a title.  However, if it was NOT inside of anchor tags, then I would put anchor tags around it.

ColdFusion makes inserting the text rather simple, but doesn't have a string manipulation function that will tell you what elements a given string is inside of.

I'm starting to wonder if I should try and come up with a regular expression that would grab occurrences based on my criteria for the replace. . .

Comment: I will check out that page.  Thanks again!